# Error : ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Tags: php, mysql, row

Good morning

I am having some issues with this search script this morning i keep getting this error

```
! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\schoolmanagementsystem\search.php on line 24
```

My Source code Looks like this

```
<html>
<title>Search Records</title>
<head>
<body>
    <form name="" id="" method="post" action="search.php"/>
    <p> Enter Student name : <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname"/>
    <input type="submit" name="senda" value="Search Data" />

</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['senda'])){

    include 'mysqlconn.php';
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $pass, $db) or die('Cannot Connect');

    $name = $_POST['fullname'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM scores WHERE fullname = '$name'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)  or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
          echo"$row['Fullname'] .'  '. $row['studentNo'] .'  '. $row['SubjectName'] .'  '. $row['GPA'] .'  '. $row['CGPA'] .'  '. $row['SCORE']<br/>";  // Error here
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
     //$result->close();
    }

?>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Need Help Seriously

Comment: try this `echo "{$row['Fullname']} {$row['studentNo']} {$row['SubjectName']} {$row['GPA']}  {$row['CGPA']} {$row['SCORE']}<br/>";` And are you trying to concatinate those strings?

Comment: Works great! but can i put in tables <td></td> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $row['Fullname']."  ".$row['studentNo']."  ".$row['SubjectName']."  ".$row['GPA']."  ".$row['CGPA']."  ".$row['SCORE']."<br/>";  // Error here
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove `"` double quotes from starting and ending `echo`

Change

```
  echo"$row['Fullname'] .'  '. $row['studentNo'] .'  '. $row['SubjectName'] .'  '. $row['GPA'] .'  '. $row['CGPA'] .'  '. $row['SCORE']<br/>";  // Error here
```

To

```
echo $row['Fullname'] . " ". $row['studentNo']. " ". $row['SubjectName'] . " ".  $row['GPA'] . " ".  $row['CGPA'] . " ".  $row['SCORE'] . " ".  $row['SubjectName'] . "<br/>";
```